# How to install certbot inside docker NGINX image?

Tags: docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

At the moment; in order to install/renew certificates I have to install both NGINX and certbot on my host instead of the container itself and while this is working it is bringing conflicts that are not nice to manage in order to renew certs....

Could someone point me to a correct way / guide to install certbot inside an official NGINX docker image ?

I tried the debian guide but nothing is working; always missing dependecies or systemd....

here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
apt update
apt -y install snapd
snap install core
snap refresh core
snap install --classic certbot
ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
```

at `snap install core` I get `error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/core": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory`

so I tried this: [umask solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258137/cannot-communicate-with-server-post-http-localhost-v2-apps-dial-unix-run-sn) but I am stuck with systemd missing

I feel like this is just going in the wrong direction...

Comment: Do you need certbot to be installed in your webserver image? Usually, certificates are mounted through a volume. From your error message: looks like snap requires snapd to be running. In containers, systemd won't be running (neither during build or execution). You might find a way to start snapd while running builds, although going with another installation method would be easier for sure, eg: python/pip install certbot.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing but I can't run NGINX on both the host and my image; therefore I get conflicts when updating certs. At the moment I have to enable nginx on host then update cert then disable nginx on host. that makes no sense to me for workflow. this should be done from within the image directly

Comment: what about pip, then? "enable nginx on host then update cert": why though? your nginx container should answer the http challenge on its own.You'll find tons of examples searching on google: https://pentacent.medium.com/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71 , https://mindsers.blog/post/https-using-nginx-certbot-docker/, https://www.programonaut.com/setup-ssl-with-docker-nginx-and-lets-encrypt/#automate-ssl-certificates-with-certbot

Comment: Not sure what you mean with pip but I think your tutorial links have a good solution. I'll try to implement this. thank you

Comment: pip, is the second part of my initial comment: you can't use snap, you should use pip, "pip install certbot", having installed python runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There are [some alternatives](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) to the recommended snap installation method.

I encountered the same issue as yours and I resolved it using the pip approach.

Try pip following this instruction:

> Instructions for installing Certbot through pip can be found at
> https://certbot.eff.org/instructions by selecting your server software
> and then **choosing “pip” in the “System” dropdown menu**.

Answer (score 0):

A contributor might be a specific IP going to the Nginx container, and it connected through the bridge to the Certbot container

I've seen several docker-compose guides that more or less expect you to run those two containers, on the VM's IP, for port 443/80. In this case since the docker containers share the VM's IP, this works, certbot does the lifting instead of nginx.

Example WordPress Docker using MACVLAN:
https://www.nova-labs.net/wordpress-php-fpm-nginx-mysql-wpcli-in-docker-stack-via-docker-compose/

When you do use MACVLAN, you cannot actually answer the requests response with certbot because it isn't assigned the IP and is on its own internal bridge, nginx doesn't respond/answer, certbot does/would.  That is why the plugin turns off Nginx. If I'm wrong here please let me know.

This appears to address the issue with more toolkits included:
https://github.com/JonasAlfredsson/docker-nginx-certbot/blob/master/src/Dockerfile

I'm just starting to research/build this detail.